# Pasar valor de un servlet a otro

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, netbeans, servlets

*Buenas, esto diseñando un trabajo y necesito listar una serie de artículos correspondientes a un `id` en `jsp` con `servlets` el problema es que me tira `null` el valor de la variable. Tengo este `jsp` donde se carga el **id**:

```
<div class="w3-container">
                <ul class="w3-ul w3-card-4" style="width: 65%;">
                    <c:forEach items="${lista}" var="P">
                        <li class="w3-bar">
                            <div class="w3-bar-item">
                                <label id="id" name="id" hidden>${P.id}</label>
                                <img src="imagenes/panditas.jpg" class="w3-bar-item w3-circle w3-hide-small" style="width:85px">
                                <span class="w3-large" style="line-height: 70px">${P.nombreCompleto1} - ${P.nombreCompleto2}</span><br>
                                <form method="POST" action="listaArticulosPreciosParejas">
                                    <button>Ver lista</button>
                                </form>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                    </c:forEach>
                </ul>
            </div>
```

Claramente, se ve el **ID**:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Así cargo los datos:

```
public ArrayList<Parejas> parejasListas(){
    ArrayList<Parejas> lista = new ArrayList<>();
    try{
        abrirConexion();
        statement = conexion.createStatement();
        resultSet = statement.executeQuery("SELECT p.idP, p.nombre1 + ' '  + p.apellido1 AS nombreCompletoUno, "
                + "p.nombre2 + ' '  + p.apellido2 AS nombreCompletoDos, c.denominacionC "
                + "FROM pareja p "
                + "INNER JOIN comercio c "
                + "ON p.idC = c.idC "
                + "WHERE c.idC = 1");
        while(resultSet.next()){
           Parejas parejas = new Parejas();
           parejas.setId(resultSet.getInt(1));
           parejas.setNombreCompleto1(resultSet.getString(2));
           parejas.setNombreCompleto2(resultSet.getString(3));
           parejas.setComercio(resultSet.getString(4));
           lista.add(parejas);
        }
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("Ha ocurrido un error al mostrar las parejas: " + e.getMessage());
    }finally{
        try{
            cerrarConexion();
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("Error al cerrar la conexión: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
    return lista;
}
```

Este es su `servlet`:

```
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    Conexiones conexionSQL = new Conexiones();
    ArrayList<Parejas> lista = conexionSQL.parejasListas();
    request.setAttribute("lista", lista);
    RequestDispatcher requestDispatcher = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/ListaPAre.jsp");
    requestDispatcher.forward(request, response);
}
```

Ahora, tengo esta consulta a `SQL Server` para cargar los artículos correspondientes a ese **ID**:

```
public ArrayList<Articulos> articulosLista(Articulos a){
        ArrayList<Articulos> lista = new ArrayList<>();
        try{
            abrirConexion();
            statement = conexion.createStatement();
            resultSet = statement.executeQuery("SELECT a.idA, a.codigo, a.denominacionA, a.precioUnitario, "
                    + "                         ta.denominacionTA, p.nombre1 + ' ' + p.apellido1, "
                    + "                         p.nombre2 + ' ' + p.apellido2  "
                    + "                         FROM articulo a "
                    + "                         INNER JOIN tipoArticulo ta ON a.idTA = ta.idTA "
                    + "                         INNER JOIN pareja p ON a.idPa = p.idP "
                    + "                         WHERE p.idP = ?" );
            while(resultSet.next()){
               Articulos articulos = new Articulos();
               articulos.setIdA(resultSet.getInt(1));
               articulos.setCodigo(resultSet.getString(2));
               articulos.setDenominacion(resultSet.getString(3));
               articulos.setPrecioUnitario(resultSet.getDouble(4));
               articulos.setIdTA(resultSet.getString(5));
               articulos.setP1(resultSet.getString(6));
               articulos.setP2(resultSet.getString(7));
               lista.add(articulos);
            }
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("Ha ocurrido un error al mostrar las parejas: " + e.getMessage());
        }finally{
            try{
                cerrarConexion();
            }catch(Exception e){
                System.out.println("Error al cerrar la conexión: " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
        return lista;
    }
```

Este es el `jsp`:

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/botones.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/imagen.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/menu.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/login/login.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/iconos.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/login/loginNav.css">
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/a076d05399.js"></script>
        <title>Lista Parejas</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        
        <div class="topnav">
            <a href="index.html"><i class="fas fa-home" style="font-size:24; padding-right: 10px;"></i>Inicio</a>
        </div>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <center>
            <div class="container">
                <table>
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Pareja</th>
                            <th>Artículo</th>
                            <th>Precio</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <c:forEach items="${lista}" var="A">
                            <tr>
                                <td>${A.denominacionA}</td>
                                <td>${A.p1}</td>
                                <td>${A.p2}</td>
                            </tr>
                        </c:forEach>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </center>
    </body>
</html>
```

Este es el `servlet`:

```
@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    processRequest(request, response);
    
    String idA = request.getParameter("id");
    Articulos articulos = new Articulos();
    articulos.setIdA(Integer.parseInt(idA));
    ArrayList<Articulos> lista = new ArrayList<Articulos>();
    Conexiones conexiones = new Conexiones();
    lista = conexiones.articulosLista(articulos);
    request.setAttribute("lista", lista);
    RequestDispatcher requestDispatcher = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/listaParejasArticulosPrecios.jsp");
    requestDispatcher.forward(request, response);
}
```

Cuando debugeo me dice que `String idA = request.getParameter("id");` esa línea tiene un valor `null`, ¿Cómo puedo solucionarlo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para que el request obtenga el valor del parámetro "id", debes especificar en la url ese parámetro en el momento en el que consumas ese servlet.

Por ejemplo, si la url de tu servlet es "api/listar-articulos", debes especificar el parámetro "id" de la siguiente manera. "api/listar-articulos?id=1".

Comment: O sea, que debo poner en el form esto: `<form action="miservlet?id=${P.id}">`?

Comment: Si, también debes indicar el **method** `<form action="miservlet?id=${P.id}" method="post">` Ya que en tu servlet estás indicando que quieres capturar el id por el método _post_

Comment: Bien, pues, consigo que el valor del `ID` esté en la url pero, ¿Cómo lo aplico en el otro servlet? Actualicé mi código para que veas

Comment: Ya entiendo un poco lo que quieres hacer. Para que ese id se envíe al servlet, debes conseguirlo añadiendo al formulario, el valor id como si fuera un input, pero hidden de la siguiente forma. `<input type="hidden" value="${P.id}" name="id" />` eso lo debes agregar dentro del form como si fuera un input más.